# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+kx)}$

Tags: limits

How do you evaluate  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+kx)}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try L'hospital rule.

Comment: I'm sorry, why the downvote? I'd really like to know.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't show any effort to solve problem. Just saying (I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+kx)}
 &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+kx)}{x}\\
  &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{k}{1+kx}}{1} && \text{l'Hospital's rule}\\
  &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{k}{1+kx}\\
  &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{k/x}{1/x+k}\\
  &= \frac{0}{0+k}\\
  &= \frac{0}{k}\\
    &= 0\\
\end{align*}

Comment: where $k\ne 0$.